# How to show order total components in a block?

Tags: 7, commerce

I would like to create a block that shows the current user's order totals including all components, as follows:

> ```
>  - Subtotal
>  - Discount or coupon
>  - Sales tax
>  - Total
> ```

I would be happy with a block that simply renders the footer of the shopping cart view. I've played around with *commerce-line-item-summary.tpl.php*, but it only renders the number of items in the cart and the total amount. It doesn't have to be a form, just a summary of the shopping cart totals.

I would like to show this block during the checkout process in a sidebar region.

Any ideas how to create this?

Comment: Which e-commerce module are you using?

Comment: Commerce has a "Commerce Order: Order total" component that can be used in Views-  it does exactly what you're looking for

Comment: Drupal Commerce Kickstart

Comment: Thank you @Clive - that was exactly what I was looking for. Unbelievable how I completely overlooked that solution when it was right in front of me! :)

Comment: @Tinto I spent about half an hour looking for the same thing last week ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting @Clive from the comments above:

> Commerce has a "Commerce Order: Order total" component that can be used in Views- it does exactly what you're looking for.

Thank you!